# Map Reduce Mongo DB: Sum of ODD and EVEN numbers with elements

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to process a number series ( collection ) get sum of odd / even numbers separately along with elements considered for calculations of each.

The numberseries document structure is as follows:

```
{
_id: <Autogenerated>,
number: <any number, it can repeat. Even if it repeats, it should be added each time. >
}
```

The output is something like below( not exact but in general )

```
{ 
..
{
"odd":<result>, elements:{n1,n3,n5}
},
{
"even":<result>, elements:{n2,n4,n6}
}
..
}
```

Map Function:

```
mapf = function(){

    var value = { sum : 0, elements :[] };

    value.sum = this.number;
    value.elements.push(this.number);

    print(tojson(value));

    if( this.number % 2 != 0 ){
    emit( "odd", value );   
    }

    if( this.number % 2 == 0 ){
    emit( "even", value );  
    }
}
```

Reduce `Values` argument:

Values is an array of JSON emitted from map:

```
   [{
        "sum": 1,
        "elements": [1]
    }, {
        "sum": 3,
        "elements": [3]
    } ... ]
```

Reduce Function:

```
  reducef = function(key, values){

    var result = { sum : 0 , elements:[] };
    print("K " + key +"Values array " + tojson(values) );

    for(var i = 0; i<values.length;i++ ){

        v = values[i];

        print("Key "+key+"V.JSON"+tojson(v)+" V.SUM -> "+v.sum);

        result.sum += v.sum;
        result.elements.push(v.elements[0]);

        print(tojson(result));

    }
    return result;  
}
```

I am getting sum correctly, but the elements array is not properly getting populated. It is containing only some of the elements considered for calculations.

---

**UPDATE**

As per the answer given by [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn), I further verified my code. I found that my code, without any modification, works for small dataset, but does not work for large data-set.

Below are points which I have verified as pointed out, I found my code to be correct.

```
print("K " + key +"Values array " + tojson(values) );
```

Above line in reduce function results in following `values` object printed.

```
[{
    "sum": 1,
    "elements": [1]
}, {
    "sum": 3,
    "elements": [3]
}, {
    "sum": 5,
    "elements": [5]
}, {
    "sum": 7,
    "elements": [7]
}, {
    "sum": 9,
    "elements": [9]
}, {
    "sum": 11,
    "elements": [11]
}, {
    "sum": 13,
    "elements": [13]
}, {
    "sum": 15,
    "elements": [15]
}, {
    "sum": 17,
    "elements": [17]
}, {
    "sum": 19,
    "elements": [19]
}]
```

Hence the line to push elements to array in final results `result.elements.push(v.elements[0]);` should be correct.

In map function, before emitting, I am modifying `value.sum` as follows

```
value.sum = this.number;
```

This ensures that `sum` is **not zero** and numbers are properly getting added due to this.

- When I test this code with 20 records, 40 records, 100 records, it works perfectly.
- When I test this code with 20000 records, the sum value is correct but the element array 
  does not contain 10000 elements each( Odd and even numbers are equally distributed in collection ) .

In later case, I get below message:

**query not recording (too large)**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is a clear reason and you do appear to have read some of [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) and at least applied this rule:

> - *"the type of the return object must be identical to the type of the value emitted by the map function  ..."*

And by that this means that both the map function and the reduce function essentially have the same output, which you did:

```js
{ sum : 0, elements :[] };
```

But there was a piece of documentation that has not been understood:

> - *"MongoDB can invoke the reduce function more than once for the same key. In this case, the previous output from the reduce function for that key will become one of the input values to the next reduce function invocation for that key."*

So where the whole thing goes wrong is that you have *assumed* that since your "map" function only emits one element, that then there will be only one element in the "elements" array. A careful re-read of the above says that this is not true. And in fact the output from "reduce" will very likely be fed back into the "reduce" function again. This is indeed how mapReduce deals with a large number of values for the "values" array.

To fix it, change this in the "reduce" function:

```js
result.elements.push(v.elements[0]);
```

To this:

```js
v.elements.forEach(function(element) {
    result.elements.push(element);
}
```

And in that way, when the "reduce" function returns a result that has summed up a few "elements" already and pushed them to the list, then that "input" will be processed correctly and merged with any other "values" that come in with it.

BTW. I Think you actually meant this in your mapper:

```js
var value = { sum : 1, elements :[] };
```

Otherwise this code down here would just be summing `0`'s:

```js
result.sum += v.sum;
```

---

### But aggregate does this better

All of that said the following aggregation framework statement does the same thing but better and faster with an implementation in native code:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "type": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ { "$mod": [ "$number", 2 ] }, 0 ] },
            "even",
            "odd"
        ]},
        "number": 1
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$type",
        "sum": { "$sum": 1 },
        "elements": { "$push": "$number" }
    }}
])
```

---

And also note that in both cases you are not really "summing the elements", but rather "counting" them. So if your want the sum then the mapReduce part becomes:

```js
//result.sum += v.sum;
v.elements.forEach(function(element) {
    result.sum += element;
    result.elements.push(element);
}
```

And the aggregate part becomes:

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$type",
        "sum": { "$sum": "$number" },
        "elements": { "$push": "$number" }
    }}
```

Which *truly* sums the "odd" or "even" numbers as found in your collection.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I verified my code. I found it works for small data-set but fails for large data-set. I have added more details to clarify.

Comment: @LearnMore Read it again. This is exactly what you have been told. The "reduce" function when thrown something of 30 elements or around there with the same key does not "reduce" in one pass only. Perhaps you should even try the code and realize that when it works that the explanation as to why is clear.